TypeError $ is not a function, Summernote, Django admin add
After following all of the installation instructions for Django for Summernote, I am
getting the following error when I go to the "add" page of django admin to check if the Editor is working:

add/:814 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at initSummernote_id_content (add/:814:5)
at add/:954:5

The Sources tab reveals where exactly the problem is occurring:

It looks like Jquery is not loading for admin, which is really confusing me. Under network, the jquery file is the 4th file loaded with 200ok.

The problem is with the order that javascript files are loaded for Django admin.  To fix the order you have to:

use a form in your admin.py for the model:

class ExercisesAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):     
    form = ExerciseAdminForm
    summernote_fields = ('content',)
 

in your forms.py declare the correct order - see the reference here

class ExerciseAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = SummernoteTextField()

    class Media:
        js=["admin/js/vendor/jquery/jQuery.js", "studyspot/js/popper.min.js", "studyspot/js/bootstrap.min.js", "summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js",]
        css = {
            'all': get_theme_files(settings.SUMMERNOTE_THEME, 'base_css'),
        }

Note: bootstrap and popper have to be loaded before summernote as well as jquery.
